# Obtaining the gradient of the generalized KL divergence using matrix calculus

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I would like to use matrix calculus to find the gradient of the following function with respect to $\mathbf{y}$:

$D_{KL}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{Vy}) =  \sum_i[x_i\log\frac{x_i}{(Vy)_i} - x_i + (Vy)_i]$

$\nabla_\mathbf{y}D_{KL}  = ?$

Using differentials, I was able to make some progress:

$\mathbf{d}D_{KL}  = \mathbf{d} \sum_ix_i\log x_i-\mathbf{d} \sum_i x_i \log (Vy)_i - \mathbf{d} \sum_i x_i + \mathbf{d} \sum_i (Vy)_i$

$ = \mathbf{d} (\mathbf{x^T} \log \mathbf{x}) - \mathbf{d} (\mathbf{x^T} \log(\mathbf{Vy} ) ) - \mathbf{d} \mathbf{(x^T1)} + \mathbf{d} (\mathbf{(Vy)^T1} )  $

$=  - \mathbf{d} (\mathbf{x^T} \log(\mathbf{Vy} ) )+ \mathbf{d} (\mathbf{(Vy)^T1} )$
$= - \mathbf{x^T} \mathbf{d}(\log(\mathbf{Vy} ) )+ \mathbf{d} (\mathbf{(Vy)^T1} )$

But my knowledge of differentials stopped here. How do I continue this derivation? Ideally, I want to isolate $\mathbf{dy^T}$ on the right hand side, and then I should have the gradient.

EDIT: with the help of @greg, I can continue.

$= - \mathbf{x^T} (\mathbf{d}(\mathbf{Vy}) \oslash \mathbf{Vy} ))+ \mathbf{d} (\mathbf{(V^T1)^Ty} )$

$= - \mathbf{x^T} (\text{diag}^{-1}[\mathbf{Vy}]\mathbf{Vdy} )+ \mathbf{(V^T1)^T\mathbf{d} y}$

$\\$

$ \implies \nabla_{\mathbf{y}} D_{KL}= \left(-\mathbf{x^T}\text{diag}^{-1}[\mathbf{Vy}]\mathbf{V} +\mathbf{(V^T1)^T} \right)^T $

$=(-\mathbf{x^T}\text{diag}^{-1}[\mathbf{Vy}]\mathbf{V})^T +\mathbf{V^T1}$

$=-\mathbf{V}^T(\mathbf{x^T} \oslash (\mathbf{Vy})) +\mathbf{V^T1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the pieces that you are missing is the differential of an elementwise log function.
$$\eqalign{
d\log(z) &= dz\oslash z \\
}$$ where $\oslash$ denotes elementwise/Hadamard division. This can be converted into a regular matrix product using a diagonal matrix
$$\eqalign{
d\log(z) &= Z^{-1}dz \quad\implies\quad
Z &= {\rm Diag}(z) \\
}$$
Another piece that you're missing is the differential of a product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
z &= Vy \quad\implies\quad
dz &= V\,dy \\
}$$
And the final piece is the equivalence between the differential and the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
d\lambda &= g^Tdz
 \quad\iff\quad
 \frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial z} &= g \\
}$$
Plus a reminder that $\;(Vy)^T{\tt1} = ({V^T\tt1})^Ty$

You should be able to take it from here.